# How to convert an object to a set?

Tags: java, list, for-loop, object, set

so I have a set named "all" that contains objects Doc. Then I have another set called "partDocs" that contains other sets that contains Doc. Let's say that "all" contains = [Doc1, Doc2, Doc3]. I want partDocs to contain those sets like: [[Doc1], [Doc2], [Doc3]]. How can I do that?

I tried

```
Set<Doc> all = new HashSet<Doc>(); // contains [Doc1, Doc2, Doc3]
Set<Set<Doc>> partDocs = new HashSet<Set<Doc>>();
Set<Doc> set2 = new HashSet<Doc>();

for (i = 0; i < all.size(); i++) {
   set2.clear();
   set2.add(all.stream().toList().get(i)); // adds the i.th element of the all set
   partDocs.add(set2);
}
```

However when I do this, partDocs only has the last element of the all set, because set2 is always changing, and its last value is [Doc3]

I also tried doing below, but its syntax is wrong

```
for (i = 0; i < all.size(); i++) {
   partDocs.add(Set<allDocuments.stream().toList().get(i)>);
}
```

Does anyone have any idea about how to implement this?

Comment: This is extremely confusing. Maybe you should start by reading the javadoc for the Set interface carefully first. And a good tutorial about java collections. See, your code to add the elements of `all` to set2 is super overkill. You could just do: `set2.clear(); set2.addAll(all)`. Thing is: I really do not understand what you want to do. So really carefully list the **objects** you have in your INPUT sets, and describe EXACTLY how your OUTPUT sets should look like.

Comment: What is the difference between all and set2?

Comment: Also,  `sat2` looks like a typo .

Comment: What I'm trying to do is turn [doc1, doc2, doc3] into 3 different sets, which will be contained by partDocs like this [[doc1],[doc2],[doc3]]. I didnt explain why I want to use this in my program because it would have been a very long post

Comment: all = [doc1, doc2, doc3] 
set2 is empty at the start, but during the loop it takes the value of the i.th element at "all", so when i = 0, set2 = [doc1], and then when i=1, set2.clear() happens, set becomes empty and then set2 = [doc2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you actually want to do this. It seems like very confusing code but try the following:

```
Set<Set<Doc>> partDocs = new HashSet<Set<Doc>>();
Set<Doc> all = new HashSet<>();

for(Doc doc : all) {
    partDocs.add(Set.of(doc));
}
```

And now you have a set (partDocs) that contains sets which contain docs

Comment: If this worked for you please check it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

The invalidation of `set2` is flawed.

Instead of

```
set2.clear();
```

it should be

```
set2 = new HashSet<Doc>();
```

---

This particular bug may be easier to understand if we use a list for `partDocs`

```
List<Set<Doc>> partDocs = new ArrayList<Set<Doc>>();
```

which results in

```
[[Doc3], [Doc3], [Doc3]]
```

Essentially, we are adding the same `Set` to the `List` and since we are using the same reference, consecutive calls to `set2.clear()` and `set2.add()` will affect both the local variable and the `Set` in the `List`.

Going back to `partDocs` being a `Set`, it will end up with only one entry, because a `Set` guarantees to not contain duplicate values and three identical instances are  of course duplicates.

---

So, to fix this bug, we must ensure that the three objects added to `partDocs` are truly distinct, which is accomplished (partly) by the new invalidation routine

```
set2 = new HashSet<Doc>();
```

and otherwise by the fact that we add a different element to it each time.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! I didn't know about this